# I'm making a search with PHP, SQL and JqueryUI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, search

I'm making a search with PHP, SQL and JqueryUI, this is the url: http://digital-axioma.com.co/top100/

Currently the users can look for the input called “Nombre” but I need that the users can look for the input called “Nombre” or input called “Razón Social” or input called “Ciudad”.

This is code:

```html
<?php
 class Conexion extends mysqli {
  public function __construct(){
   parent::__construct("localhost","root","","top");
   $this->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
   $this->connect_errno ? die("Error con la conexion") : $x = "Conectado";
   unset($x);
  }

/*The mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.*/
  public function recorrer($y){
   return mysqli_fetch_array($y);
  }

/* The mysqli_num_rows() function returns the number of rows in a result set */
  public function rows($y){
   return mysqli_num_rows($y);
  }
 }
?>
```

```html
<?php
 include("class.conection.php");

 class Ajax {

  public $buscador;
  public function Buscar($a){
   
   $db = new Conexion();
   $this->buscador = $db->real_escape_string($a);
   $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM top100seis WHERE Nombre LIKE '%$this->buscador%';");

   while($array = $db->recorrer($sql)){
    $resultado[] = $array["Nombre"];
   }
   
   return $resultado;
  }
 }

$busqueda = new Ajax();
echo json_encode($busqueda->Buscar($_GET["term"]));
?>
```

```html
<aside id="buscador">
        <div class="container">
            <form method="GET" id="formulario-busqueda">
                <div class="caja8">
                   <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" placeholder="Buscar" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="caja2">
                    <button type="submit" id="boton-buscar"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use UNION in your mysql

```
SELECT * FROM top100seis WHERE Nombre LIKE '%$this->buscador%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM top100seis WHERE Razón Social LIKE '%$this->buscador%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM top100seis WHERE Ciudad LIKE '%$this->buscador%'
```

Comment: .. yes, use or if it's in the same table, union will work in both cases but it's slower.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my job.